# Bound Silverlight Combobox not showing default value with EnumBinder

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, combobox, enums

My models use enums for fixed multiple selections. I'm using Dean Chalk's EnumBinder, found  at http://deanchalk.me.uk/post/Enumeration-Binding-In-Silverlight.aspx , to bind to a combo box. Everything seems to work great except the default value isn't shown. The selected index is -1, and it doesn't matter if I bind to SelectedItem or SelectedValue. The combobox works fine otherwise. I have no problems with default values with any other bound comboboxes.

enumbindingsupport.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

/* All of this was once just part of the RichClient sub-namespace
 * but it has its uses elsewhere, so it has been moved. 
 */

/// <summary>
/// Container for enumeration values.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// http://deanchalk.me.uk/post/Enumeration-Binding-In-Silverlight.aspx
/// </remarks>
public sealed class EnumContainer
{
    public int EnumValue { get; set; }
    public string EnumDescription { get; set; }
    public object EnumOriginalValue { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() {
        return EnumDescription;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj is EnumContainer)
            return EnumValue.Equals((int)((EnumContainer)obj).EnumValue);
        return EnumValue.Equals((int)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return EnumValue.GetHashCode();
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// A collection to store a list of EnumContainers that hold enum values.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// http://deanchalk.me.uk/post/Enumeration-Binding-In-Silverlight.aspx
/// </remarks>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class EnumCollection<T> : List<EnumContainer> where T : struct
{
    public EnumCollection() {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("This class only supports Enum types");
        var fields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var field in fields) {
            var container = new EnumContainer();
            container.EnumOriginalValue = field.GetValue(null);
            container.EnumValue = (int)field.GetValue(null);
            container.EnumDescription = field.Name;
            var atts = field.GetCustomAttributes(false);
            foreach (var att in atts)
                if (att is DescriptionAttribute) {
                    container.EnumDescription = ((DescriptionAttribute)att).Description;
                    break;
                }
            Add(container);
        }

    }
}
```

enumvalueconverter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

/// <summary>
/// Supports two-way binding of enumerations.
/// </summary>
public class EnumValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                            CultureInfo culture) {
        return (int)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                            CultureInfo culture) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        if (value.GetType() == targetType)
            return value;
        return ((EnumContainer)value).EnumOriginalValue;
    }
}
```

enum used:

```
/// <summary>
/// Describes the available sorting options.
/// </summary>
public enum PeopleSortOptionsEnum
{

    [Display(Order = 10)]
    [Description("First Name, Last Name")]
    FirstNameThenLastName,

    [Display(Order = 20)]
    [Description("Last Name, First Name")]
    LastNameThenFirstName,

    [Display(Order = 30)]
    Grade,

    [Display(Order = 40)]
    Gender,

    [Display(Order = 50)]
    Age
}
```

property on my model:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the list for the enumeration to bind to.
    /// </summary>
    public EnumCollection<PeopleSortOptionsEnum> AvailableSortOptions
    {
        get { return new EnumCollection<PeopleSortOptionsEnum>(); }
    }
```

XAML snippet:

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableSortOptions, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Preferences.SortOrder, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="32" Margin="48,31,0,0" x:Name="cboSort" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Where Preferences.SortOrder is of type PeopleSortOptionsEnum, the converter is in my app.xaml as a converter for all enum types.

Anyone have any idea why it won't set the index to the currently selected value? I'm about to just throw some code in the codebehind to set the selectedindex to the currently selected value on load, but I feel so dirty just thinking about it.

Besides this issue, it works wonderfully, so thanks Dean!

**Edit** Adding the Preferences.SortOrder code:

```
public PeopleSortOptionsEnum SortOrder 
{ 
  get { return sortOrder; } 
  set 
  { 
    if (sortOrder != value) 
    { 
      sortOrder = value; 
      PropertyHasChanged("SortOrder"); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: What does the preferences class look like?

Comment: It's just a POCO class contained in my model that is a property bag and implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I have an instance of the class in the model, and it's a separate class so I can easily serialize it to storage.

Comment: Ok, can you at least post the Preferences.SortOrder code?

Comment: public PeopleSortOptionsEnum SortOrder
 {
  get { return sortOrder; }
  set 
  {
   if (sortOrder != value)
   {
    sortOrder = value;
    PropertyHasChanged("SortOrder");
   }
  }
 }

Comment: It's just a standard property. Like I said before, I have no problems with any other properties, and I'm very sure it's an issue with the code posted above or the SL combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the Convert method on your enum converter class:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                        CultureInfo culture) {
    return (int)value;
}
```

When the combobox SelectedItem is gets the value from SortOrder it is return in Enum value which this converter is converting to an int. However, the combobox items is a collection of EnumContainer objects, not ints. So it fails to set the selected item.

To resolve the issue you have to do two things. First change your combobox bindings and set the SelectedValuePath:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableSortOptions}" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SortOrder, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}}" 
          SelectedValuePath="EnumOriginalValue"/>
```

Second you have to slightly modify the Convert method on your converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  return value;
}
```

Once I made those two changes it started working as expected.